# You are taking too long

Tags: grammar

"What is taking her so long?"

We normally say that when we have been waiting a person for a long time.

Context:

My son has been waiting his mother for a long time in car.

When my wife went in car.

My son told my wife.

```
"You are taking too long."
```

Does the phrase above can be use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "You are taking too long."

Yes, "taking too long" and variations like "taking a while" and "taking a bit" are common expressions in English.

> Does the phrase above can be use?

"Can the phrase above be used?" or "Can the phrase above be of use?"